# Jenkins JDK17 Docker still using JDK9?

Tags: docker, jenkins, java

I installed docker for Jenkins `JDK17`

```shell
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:jdk17
```

Reason being I run a single node (I know isn't the best practice, but for trying out) and my target application is also a **Java build**.

Now, the issue is when I checked the version in a build, it is still Java `9` Not `17`! Results in build failures.

```shell
+ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

How can I get `JDK 17` so that I can build my application using Jenkins Docker?

Comment: This is probably less of a question and more of a bug that should be reported https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues 
`
But I dont expect this is a bug. What happens if you run `which java`. The java install should be here https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/d8d4c1146a3ea3464573842b5390802331ed25e5/17/debian/bullseye/hotspot/Dockerfile#L102-L104

Answer (score 1):

Actually looks like I haven't done a great build-setup here. The way to correctly do this is not trying to change the default JDK (even though I still think there's an issue in the Docker..). What really required is a "Tool" section under JDK section for the builds to work with the custom JDK. So the notion from Jenkins, the Agent JDK is what I need, and not to worry about the Controller JDK really.

A great video that I came across that helped:

[How to Configure a JDK in Jenkins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx3XK82BZPk)